# add html hyperlink tag site in text

Tags: python, html

I'm new in Python and working on kind of converter from plain text, to "readable" html.
So I've made almost all except making links to cool hyperlinks.

So, I need find and replace in text links, there is an example :

Input:

```
random_text
another_random_text: https://example.com/random_text
random_text
```

Output:

```
random_text
another_random_text: <a href="https://example.com/random_text">example.com</a>
random_text
```

I'm stucked with it and have no idea how to detect a link and cut it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression for the task ([Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/H1vLhb/1)). For example:

```
import re

s = '''
random_text
another_random_text: https://example.com/random_text
random_text
'''

s = re.sub(r'(https?://([^/]+)(?:[^\s]*))', r'<a href="\1">\2</a>', s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
random_text
another_random_text: <a href="https://example.com/random_text">example.com</a>
random_text
```